# Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805 - Unable to close output stream

Tags: ftp, stream, output, aptana

Since a few days I have issues with Aptana 3 using FTP connections to some different servers. Suddenly and totally sporadic but very often Aptana is unable to save a file to server. It shows the progress bar in the down the right side and after a while I get the error

```
 unable to close output stream
```

I've deleted the error log file as mentioned in another post here but it didn't help.

When I take a look at the ftp servers activity monitor the client is shown with "STOR" of the file that should be saved but without any activity.

Server is Win2008R2 and Win2003 with Gene6FTP. Nothing has changed server sided.

Please let me know if I missed any necessary information.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just read that the reason could be low disk space on the server. Not for me because there is plenty of free space.

Answer (score 0):

Apologize for my bad english, I speak only Spanish. I had the same problem, was that it had no permission to add files to the server. In my local server, i have permissions to write, read, modify, add or delete. Well, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Would you please provide the way how you solved the problem? That would be very helpful to me because the problem still consists and I haven't found a solution yet. Thank you in advance.